# Is every topological submanifold of codimension $0$ open?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a topological manifold, and consider $N\subset M$ with the subspace topology.

Assume $N$ is a topological manifold of codimension $0$. Must it be open in $M$?

It is clearly the case for any locally flat submanifold.
But does it hold in general? ([See discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004039/definiton-of-submanifold-of-topological-manifold) on possibilities of defining submanifolds).

(I know this holds in the smooth case, but there we have the inverse function theorem, so we get a local diffeomorphism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a direct consequence of the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain#Generalizations).

Comment: How? I am afraid I do not see it yet...

Comment: The inclusion $i : N \to M$ is a continuous one-to-one map between two $\dim M$-dimensional manifolds, so by the invariance of domain it is open. $N$ is tautologically open in itself, so $ N = i[N]$ is open in $M$.